# APPCRASH Inside Switch Statement - C

Tags: c, audio

I'm trying to write a program that will perform a linear fade-in, linear fade-out, or linear cross-fade, as specified by the user, to '.au'` files.

I've made a `switch` statement based on an `int` input by the user, which will be directed to one of three cases, depending on the value of the input.

In each of these cases I prompt the user to entire the full path of the file he/she wants to use for the fades, and then afterwards open up a file to write the fades to.

However, it seems that after the file gets opened, my program crashes. I'm pretty sure I'm using `switch` correctly, and I've made sure to close each file at the end, so I'm not sure why the program keeps crashing.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *f1, *f2, *fout;
    int r1, choice;
    float dr;
    char yn = 'y', path1[100], path2[100];

    while(yn == 'y' || yn == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Fade Out(1) Fade In(2) Cross-fade(3): ");
        scanf("%i", &choice);

        printf("Specify duration of fade (in seconds): ");
        scanf("%d", &dr);
        switch(choice) 
        {
            case(1):
                printf("Please specify full path of file you want to fade out\n");
                scanf("%s", path1);
                f1 = fopen(path1, "r");
                if(f1 == NULL) 
                {
                    printf("Incorrect file path specifiation. Program terminating...\n");
                    break;
                }
                fout = fopen("out.au", "w");
                //r1 = read_header(f1, NULL, fout, choice, dr);
                printf("We've gotten this far!\n");
                break;
            case(2):
                printf("Please specify full path of file you want to fade in\n");
                scanf("%s", path1);
                f1 = fopen(path1, "r");
                if(f1 == NULL) 
                {
                    printf("Incorrect file path specifiation. Program terminating...\n");
                    break;
                }
                fout = fopen("out.au", "w");
                //r1 = read_header(f1, NULL, fout, choice, dr);
                break;
            case(3):
                printf("Specify first file used to cross-fade\n");
                scanf("%s", path1);
                printf("Specify second file used in cross-fade\n");
                scanf("%s", path2);
                f1 = fopen(path1, "r");
                f2 = fopen(path2, "r");
                if((f1 == NULL || f2 == NULL))
                {
                    if(f1 == NULL)
                        printf("Incorrect file path specification for first file. Program terminating...\n");
                    else
                        printf("Incorrect file path specification for second file. Program terminating...\n");
                    break;
                }
                fout = fopen("out.au", "w");
                //r1 = read_header(f1, f2, fout, choice, dr);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Not a valid option.\n");
                break;
        }
        fclose(f1);
        if(f2 != NULL)
            fclose(f2);
        fclose(fout);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Again (y/n)? ");
        scanf("%c", &yn);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another flaw is, you're closing `fout` tho you might not have opened it. Are you on linux? I could tell you how to find out the reason for the crash with `gdb`.

Comment: No, I'm using Windows with MinGW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `FILE *f1, *f2, *fout` does not initialize the variables.

Then, `if(f2 != NULL)` accesses an uninitialized variable.

Worse yet, `fclose(f2)` dereferences an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You break if the file fails to open but after the switch you attempt to close the NULL pointer.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. What if I tried `if(f2 != null) fclose(f2);`?